# Upgrade to Stone Axe in Starbound

Tags: starbound

> Note: This question refers to content only found in beta. **As of 1.0 stable, the stone axe is not obtainable.** While pickaxes and drills still exist and can be used to cut wood, they are not craftable or upgradable and have limited use. The only upgradable tool for cutting wood is the Matter Manipulator.

I have defeated the first boss in Starbound and am roaming around in the Beta Sector. I have upgraded my pickaxe to gold, and it is working really great.

I was wondering if there are similar upgrades for the axes. Assuming that there would of course be an upgrade to axes, I crafted an Ice Axe (Human racial steel Axe), but it wouldn't chop any trees. Similarly for the Iron Axe, I came upon this in a wiki:

> Although you can make an iron axe after making an iron anvil, the Iron Axe is a weapon, and not a tool for cutting trees.

Does that mean we're stuck with the Stone Axe for all our wood needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the current Beta v. Enraged Koala, the only tools that can be directly upgraded are pickaxes, and their cousins, drills. The Stone Axe is the only woodcutting tool available in the game, though a [chainsaw](http://starbound.gamepedia.com/Chainsaw) does exist in the game's files (but is unobtainable).

There are, however, a number of [tool-related mods](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?forums/tools.122/) which might have something, if you want. And, there's always the possibility of just about anything being added in an update, including that chainsaw finally becoming obtainable.